# Finding the solution to $x(e^x)+\ln(x)+c = 0$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, lambert-w

> How can I find the solution to $x(e^x)+\ln(x)+c = 0$, where $c$ is constant?

I believe the solution is solved using [Lambert $W$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and derivatives, but I can't figure it out. I can't find any ideas. Can someone tell me the idea behind this problem?

Comment: I don't think we can find a closed expression in the way of finding roots. However,  notice that $f(x)=xe^{x}+\ln(x)$ is continuous because is product and sums of continuous functions, then there exists a root. Then, we can find an approximation for the roots using Numerical Methods.

Comment: Better apply numerical methods without searching for a possible expression involving Lambert-W. I do not know whether Lambert-W helps here at all.

Comment: We can prove that there's a unique solution in the interval $(0,\infty)$. But I don't think a closed form could be given.

Comment: @Peter. It helps because it gives an upper bound of the solution which is good for any solver.

Comment: Improved and much better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the two functions
$$f(x)=x e^x+\log(x)+c \qquad \text{and} \qquad g(x)=x+\log(x)+c$$ Since $f(x)>g(x)$, the solution of $f(x)=0$ is smaller than
$$a=W\left(e^{-c}\right)\qquad \text{and} \qquad
f(a)=\log \left(W\left(e^{-c}\right)\right)+c+e^{-c}$$ is always positive.

Expanding $f(x)$ as an infinite series around $x=a$ gives
$$f(x)=\left(e^a a+\log (a)+c\right)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bigg[\frac{e^a (a+n)}{\Gamma (n+1)}-(-1)^n\frac{ a^{-n}}{n} \Bigg](x-a)^n$$ Truncating to some order and using series reversion with (for easier notations)
$$k=\left(e^a a+\log (a)+c\right)\qquad \text{and} \qquad b_n=\frac{e^a (a+n)}{\Gamma (n+1)}-(-1)^n\frac{ a^{-n}}{n}$$

$$\color{blue}{x=a-\frac k{b_1}-\frac{b_2 k^2}{b_1^3}+\frac{\left(b_1 b_3-2 b_2^2\right) k^3}{b_1^5}-\frac{\left(5 b_2^3-5 b_1 b_3 b_2+b_1^2 b_4\right) k^4}{b_1^7}+\cdots}$$

Trying for a few values of $c$, the results

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
c & \text{approximation} & \text{solution}\\
 0.00 & \color{red}{0.47067}41211 &  0.4706753748 \\
 0.25 & \color{red}{0.41522}37046 &  0.4152225064 \\
 0.50 & \color{red}{0.361196}8377 &  0.3611964501 \\
 0.75 & \color{red}{0.3097050}650 &  0.3097050036 \\
 1.00 & \color{red}{0.2618048}436 &  0.2618048383 \\
 1.25 & \color{red}{0.218353889}6 &  0.2183538895 \\
 1.50 & \color{red}{0.1798994651} &  0.1798994651 
\end{array}
\right)$$ which seem to be decent.

For sure, we could take more terms in the expansion in terms of $t$ and obtain better results.